# How to calculate password strength?

Tags: math, passwords, password-protection

I'm using a certain electronic currency and they use pass phrases as passwords.
Basically every password is 12 English **words** long. How can I calculate how secure this is?
I don't know much about these things, but 12 words seem rather feasible with a dictionary attack (at least in my mind).

Naturally I'm worried how secure this is so instead of just asking if it is, I'd like to know methods on calculating it myself (you can spoil the answer, of course).

Any advice, links, literature recommendations, etc are welcome!

**PS:** How long it would take for an average computer to get an valid pass phrase with the details I gave above? I need to know if I have to keep making new accounts regularly to transfer funds to if it really doesn't take that much effort. I'd also appreciate any information on how to calculate that as well, but is not the main issue here. Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest you go here. http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Chek this http://blog.webernetz.net/2013/07/30/password-strengthentropy-characters-vs-words/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's all a question of [entropy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language). How many different symbols are there to test ?

Traditionally, passwords are a string of characters. Symbols are then characters. If you use lower case letters only a-z is a range of 26 possible letters. With upper case and numbers, you get 62 symbols. With all special symbols that are in the ASCII set (so without fancy encodings) you get over 90 possible symbols already. In your case, a symbol is a word.

From [this question on Oxford dictionaries’ website](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language) I would gather there are 115000 words that you could expect (without obsolete and derivatives).

To compute the number of combinations, you have to realize that for each possible symbol at a given position, you have the choice of every possible character at another position. With strings of characters, if your password starts with a $, you still have any character for the other positions. This means that we have to multiply the number of possible symbols for each symbol position. Thus with 2 characters that have s possible symbols, you have `s*s` possibilities. In general, you would have for `c` characters `s`<sup>`c`</sup> possibilities for a password.

Note that this means that in the case of dictionary words, you put random words instead of making sentences !

In your case, there are 115000<sup>12</sup> possibilities, which is about 5.3*10<sup>60</sup>. So a huge lot.

The time to brute-force a password is then given by how much time `t` it takes to test a password, and the number of attempts, in your case `t × 2.65 × 10^60` if you enumerate all combinations in a random order, and `t × 5.3 × 10^60` if you try word combinations completely at random.

Comment: Wonderful explanation with some research, combinatorics and statistics in there for proofiness.

Comment: @Cimbali I think you need to check your expected value calculation.  5.3*10^60 attempts will always find the password since that many trials defines an exhaustive search.  However, the expected value is actually half that time because you will correctly guess the password half the time when you have exhaustively tried half the possible passwords.  So the expected = average number of tries needed is actually 2.65*10^60.  In this case the geometric distribution doesn't apply because the trials are not random.

Comment: @anband Random attempts are not an exhaustive search. The more random passwords you generate, the higher the chances that you generate a password you already tested. You are talking about enumerating all possibilities.

Comment: @Cimbali But somebody trying to crack a password using brute force isn't going to use Bernoulli trials where the same password may be tried multiple times against a given hash.  Instead a particular password will be tried once and if it doesn't work, will not be tried again.  The geometric distribution doesn't account for this memory of previous attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have created the function on react-js to calculate the strenght of the password on the basic of some condition ..

A password must contain ATLEAST one Uppercase
A password must contain ATLEAST one lowercase
A password must contain ATLEAST one specialchar
A password must contain ATLEAST one Number
lenght of password must be 8 or above

```
    export const PasswordStrenght: any = (password: string) => {
        // Initial Percentage 
        let percentage: number = 0;
        // Special character regex enter code here
        const specialChars = /[ `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.\/?~]/;
        const ownWeight : number = 20; 
        // Atleat one number
        if (/\d/.test(password)) {
            percentage = percentage + ownWeight;
        }
        // Atleat one lowercase alphabet
        if (/.*[a-z].*/.test(password)) {
            percentage = percentage + ownWeight;
        }
        // Atleat one uppercase alphabet
        if (/.*[A-Z].*/.test(password)) {
            percentage = percentage + ownWeight;
        }
        // Atleat one special character
        if (specialChars.test(password)) {
            percentage = percentage + ownWeight;
        }
        // lenght altest 8 or above 
        if (password.length >= 8) {
            percentage = percentage + ownWeight;
        }
        return percentage;
    };
```